# Workers fails to deserialize with rasterio

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes

after a deploy over Google Cloud the official Dask Helm chart I've update the environment with some extra conda packages, specifically xarray and rasterio.
If I try to run my code I'm getting back this error from the workers log and the procedure stops.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 743,
>   in _run_callback ret = callback() File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 767,
>   in _discard_future_result future.result() File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in
>   run yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) # type: ignore File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line
>   661, in handle_scheduler self.ensure_computing]) File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in
>   run value = future.result() File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in
>   run yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) # type: ignore File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line
>   386, in handle_stream msgs = yield comm.read() File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in
>   run value = future.result() File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in
>   run yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) # type: ignore File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line
>   206, in read deserializers=deserializers) File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in
>   run value = future.result() File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in
>   wrapper yielded = next(result) File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py",
>   line 82, in from_frames res = _from_frames() File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py",
>   line 68, in _from_frames deserializers=deserializers) File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py",
>   line 132, in loads value = _deserialize(head, fs,
>   deserializers=deserializers) File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py",
>   line 184, in deserialize return loads(header, frames) File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py",
>   line 57, in pickle_loads return pickle.loads(b''.join(frames)) File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py",
>   line 59, in loads return pickle.loads(x) File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasterio/**init**.py", line
>   22, in  from rasterio._base import gdal_version ImportError:
>   libzstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

For my understanding problem seems to be the missing or corrupted library libzstdl, am I right? I can't try to reinstall it as I don't have the admin rights. The helm carts is based on the official dask/docker version 
Can any one help me to find on which channel is better to report this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved add in in the helm file:

```
env:
    - name: EXTRA_APT_PACKAGES
      value : libzstd1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your versions are not the same across all of your clients and workers.  Note that the `EXTRA_CONDA_PACKAGES=` environment variable that you're using needs to be used both in the client and the worker specs, not just one.

You might also try `client.get_versions(check=True)` to verify that some of the packages that are more central to Dask are synchronized.